# How to call a variable inside another function

Tags: glade

**Hi,i have 2 functions that do a printf of what a i put in a text entry (used glade for GUI).
like this:**

```
void on_adress_activate(GtkWidget * adress, GdkEvent * event, gpointer data)
{
const gchar *adress_text;
adress_text=gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (adress));
printf ("IP Adress: %s\n",adress_text);
}

void on_port_activate(GtkWidget * port, GdkEvent * event, gpointer data)
{
const gchar *port_text;
port_text=gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (port));
printf ("Port Number: %s\n",port_text);
}
```

**Now i need to call the values of port_text and adress_text in another function that when i click a button on gui it should display another printf of them:**

```
void on_connect_clicked(GtkWidget * widget, gpointer user_data)
{
printf("Connection done%s,port%s\n",adress_text,port_text);
}
```

**Is there a way to do this? please correct my code.I hope i was clear. 
Thanks in advance**

Comment: What do you think the `user_data` argument of the function is there for?

Answer (score 0):

in the function where you put your variable put

```
global name_of_variable
```